# Jquery UI dialog always get empty input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

- So I try to get input value of #title when submit
- But it's always be "" when use submit event
- I tried to use keyup event to test it
- But it works fine...
- Here is my code

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new task">
  <form autocomplete="off" class="taskform">
    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Add title">
    <textarea placeholder="Details" id="details" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <!-- User need to press enter to submit -->
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#title').keyup(function() {
          $('#details').val($('#title').val());
        });
        $('#dialog-form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log($('#title').val());
        });
      });
    </script>
  </form>
</div>
```

Jquery UI

```
dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 370,
  width: 370,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Add task": addTask,
    Cancel: function() {
      dialog.dialog("close");
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[0].reset();
  }
});

form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function() {
  addTask();
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. What are you trying to do with the value that's not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The jQuery UI Dialog is a DIV in your HTML. It might be best to move all your script to one code block instead of loading it in different places.

Comment: Thanks for your considering, this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow. I still don't know how should I state my question. So I apologize for my mistake if things are not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var dialog;

  function dlgReset(cnt) {
    console.log("Form Reset");
    $("form", cnt).get(0).reset();
  }

  function addTask() {
    var t = $(".title", dialog).val(),
      d = $(".details", dialog).val();
    if (t == "") {
      console.log("Error: No Title");
      return false;
    }
    console.log("Add Task: '" + t + "', Details:", d);
    dlgReset(dialog);
    console.log("Close Dialog");
    dialog.dialog("close");
    return true;
  }

  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 320,
    width: 420,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Save Task",
        class: "ui-state-default",
        tabindex: "3",
        click: function() {
          console.log("Save Selected");
          addTask();
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        tabindex: "4",
        click: function() {
          console.log("Cancel Selected");
          dlgReset(this);
          console.log("Close Dialog");
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $("form", dialog).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submit | Save Selected");
    addTask();
  });

  $(".open").click(function() {
    console.log("Open Dialog")
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
em {
  color: red;
}

.ui-dialog .task {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ui-dialog button.ui-state-default {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="open">Add Task</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create New Task">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="task title" tabindex="1" placeholder="Add Title" /> <span><em>*</em> Required</span>
    <textarea placeholder="Add Details" tabindex="2" class="task details" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

This allows us to gather the details from the form and reset the form. This will happen when the `Save Task` button or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. `Cancel` will simply reset the form.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.